# Problem managing streamed data with struct pointers, some of the streamed data seems to be stored, some not with an STM32F401VE

Tags: stm32, hal

I've recently been teached about how to manage streamed data in this case for managing commands, then my code is like the following explanation: I've programmed the uart2 to receive the streamed data byte to byte and I've been storing it in a buffer, every time arrives a byte then a flag is set and the function that analizes the streamed data takes the address of the reception buffer, inside the function that analizes the streamed data I declared several pointers to a struct to manage differente kind of commands.

All the commands has a code in the first byte and a termination suffix, the suffix is 0xff 0xf 0xff and the command code are the following:

```
NEX_RET_CMD_FINISHED (0x01)
NEX_RET_SLEEP_CURRENT (0x86) (134)
NEX_RET_AWAKE_CURRENT (0x87) (135)
NEX_RET_EVENT_TOUCH_HEAD (0x65) (101)
NEX_RET_CURRENT_PAGE_ID_HEAD (0x66) 102)
NEX_RET_EVENT_POSITION_HEAD (0x67) (103)
NEX_RET_EVENT_SLEEP_POSITION_HEAD (0x68) (104)
```

the code in the stream analizer is the following

```
uint8_t analize_string(uint32_t * incomming)
{
typedef uint8_t cCode;

typedef struct
{
    cCode prefix;
    uint32_t suffix : 24;
} recvMessage;

typedef struct
{
    cCode prefix;
    uint8_t page;
} head;

typedef struct
{
    head header;
    uint32_t suffix;
} pageEvent;

typedef struct
{
    head header;
    uint8_t ident;
    uint8_t event;
    uint32_t suffix : 24;
} eventID;

typedef struct
{
    cCode prefix;
    uint8_t page;
    uint8_t ID;
    uint8_t event;
    uint32_t suffix : 24;
} eventBody;

typedef struct
{
    cCode prefix;
    uint16_t x;
    uint16_t y;
    uint8_t event;
} touchC;

uint8_t analize_string(uint8_t * incomming)
{
    static uint8_t incCounter = 0;
    recvMessage *confirm;
    confirm = (recvMessage *) incomming;
    pageEvent *pEvent;
    pEvent = (pageEvent *) incomming;
    eventID * identif;
    identif = (eventID *) incomming;
    touchEvent *sleepingEvent;
    sleepingEvent = (touchEvent *) incomming;
//  data *message;
    if((confirm->prefix == NEX_RET_CMD_FINISHED)
            && (confirm->suffix == 0xffffff))
    {
        interface.aHMI = true;
    }
    if((confirm->prefix == NEX_RET_SLEEP_CURRENT)
            && (confirm->suffix == 0xffffff))
    {
        interface.aHMI = true;
        interface.pSleep = true;
    }
    if((confirm->prefix == NEX_RET_AWAKE_CURRENT)
            && (confirm->suffix == 0xffffff))
    {
        interface.aHMI = true;
        interface.pSleep = false;
    }
    if((identif->header.prefix == NEX_RET_EVENT_TOUCH_HEAD)
                && (identif->suffix == 0xffffff))
        {
            interface.aHMI = true;
        }
    if((sleepingEvent->prefix == NEX_RET_EVENT_POSITION_HEAD)
            && (sleepingEvent->suffix == 0xffffff))
    {
        interface.aHMI = true;
    }
    if((pEvent->header.prefix == NEX_RET_CURRENT_PAGE_ID_HEAD)
            && (pEvent->suffix == 0xffffff))
    {
        interface.aHMI = true;
        interface.page = pEvent->header.page;
    }
    if( if((sleepingEvent->prefix == NEX_RET_EVENT_POSITION_HEAD)
            && (sleepingEvent->suffix == 0xffffff))
    {
        interface.aHMI = true;
    }
    if((sleepingEvent->prefix == NEX_RET_EVENT_SLEEP_POSITION_HEAD)
            && sleepingEvent->suffix)
    {
        interface.aHMI = true;
    }
    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&dbSerial, (uint8_t *) &sleepingEvent[incCounter], 1);
    if(interface.aHMI)
    {
//////      screen_handler();
        interface.aHMI = false;
    }
    incCounter++;
    if(incCounter == Long_Rec)
    {
        incCounter = 0;
    }
    receive_data((char *) &U2rxBuffer[incCounter], (uint16_t) sizeof(uint8_t));
    return incCounter;
}
in main the call to the function is treated like follows



receive_data(U2rxBuffer, sizeof(uint8_t));/* Inicializa la recepción de 1
                                     * caracter.                             */
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      if(received == true)
      {
          analize_string((uint8_t *) U2rxBuffer);
          received = false;
      }
  }
}
```

and the flag received is set in the RxCpltCallback for the uart2like follows

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    received = true;
}
```

the code of the main functions is the following

```
while (1)
{
    if(received == true)
    {
        analize_string((uint32_t *) &U2rxBuffer[0]);
        received = false;
    }
}
```

and some of the conditions to analize the stream works, some other doesn't works; by example, the conditions that compares with the macros NEX_RET_CMD_FINISHED and

NEX_RET_SLEEP_CURRENT works perfectly and those commands only has four bytes being the prefix and the suffix, the condition that works with the macro NEX_RET_EVENT_SLEEP_POSITION_HEAD also works well but the condition that works with the macro NEX_RET_EVENT_POSITION_HEAD doesn't works well thoug both commands has the same 9 bytes long, when I send to the other uart the content of the pointer sleepingEvent then it prints this

[image: Printed]

the text in the upper console s what I sent through the uart2 and the lower console is what I suposse is the content of the pointer to a struct sleepingEvent, now seeing that I can note that the content of the stream beyond the prefix is lost or not properly stored (I don't know which of that causes are) and I don't know how to solve it.

If I print directly the content of the pointer incomming then it prints what is in the lower console of the following image

[image]

what I see there is that the uart_transmit function is printing bad what is received.

NOTE: I think is more c related problem in the address assignation of the structres but I don't know.

So, can someone help my to solve the problem?

Thanks so much in advance for the help.

UPDATE: Adittional content to show why I did the definitions of the structures like that:

the code that defines the structures in the book that I mentioned to @brhans is

```
struct horse
{
    int age;
    int height;
    char name[20];
    char father[20];
    char mother[20];
} Dobbin = {
24, 17, "Dobbin", "Trigger", "Flossie"
};
```

and the explanatory figure is

[image: structure memory arrangement]

Surely I've interpreter something wrong.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very well thought out architecture.  In particular it's not very clear if you're actually checking that you've received enough bytes to comprise a message, before you go trying to check parts of the buffer.  Maybe you are, but the code doesn't make that very clear.  Or maybe you aren't, and you're comparing to random uninitialized/leftover memory...

Comment: Hi Chris, at the  moment I didn't want to check if there is enough bytes to check those condition, the function was made to enter any time a new byte is received, the reasoning fot that is if not enough bytes are received the struct members will have any content different to the content I want, so, before there are enough bytes the corresponding condition will not met then the aHMI flag will not be set.

Comment: But thanks for the comment, now I could explicitly put a condition for incCounter that doesn't allow to check any command condition untill the incCounter indicates that the U2rxBuffer received the minimal quantity of bytes to check those conditions. That will save processing time. Thanks again for the comment. Now, about the original question it goes for the side commented by brhans.

Comment: You'd have to repeatedly zero-initialize the memory every time you start over if you don't check the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to 'pack' your structs to ensure that their fields are placed as you expect them to be, particularly since you're working with 32-bit hardware.
How you do that depends on your compiler - it might be something like `__packed` or `__attribute__((packed))`.
Without this your compiler is aligning the fields inside your struct on boundaries which probably depend on their size.

Your `pageEvent` struct is a good example of this.
What you think you have is something like this:

```
{
  {
    1 byte: cCode prefix
    1 byte: uint8_t page
  } head
  4 bytes: uint32_t suffix
} pageEvent
```

but what you really have is something like this:

```
{
  {
    1 byte: cCode prefix
    1 byte: uint8_t page
  } head
>> 2 spare bytes for alignment <<
  4 bytes: uint32_t suffix
} pageEvent
```

because your compiler wants to align the `uint32_t suffix` on a 4-byte address, so it inserts 2 'invisible' bytes into your struct.
You'll have similar problems with your `touchC` struct.

Note that if your underlying hardware were an 8-bit or 16-bit device, the alignment requirement could possibly be less 'strict'. The compiler would probably be ok with placing 32-bit wide fields on 16-bit/2-byte addresses in a 16-bit device since these fields would be accessed as 2 separate memory reads by the hardware. Similarly on an 8-bit device there might be no packing needed, since every read would be an individual byte - even for 16- and 32-bit fields.

These alignment issues bit me when I started porting code from 8-bit PICs over to 16-bit dsPICs, and again (although to a lesser extent) when porting code over to 32-bit devices.
Something I've started doing recently when writing code which is intended to be portable across many different hardware platforms & compilers is to use a `static_assert` compiler directive to check the size of my structs at compile time.
For example for your `pageEvent` struct with a 24-bit suffix I would write:

```
static_assert(sizeof(pageEvent) == 5, "Error: pageEvent is wrong size!");
```

immediately after the struct typedef.
Depending on your compiler, the directive might be a little different, like `Static_Assert` or `__static_assert` or something similar.

Comment: Hi @brhans, about the pageEvent struct there is a mistake, the suffix member should be a bitfield of 24 bits like it is defined in the other structures lefting the other 8 bits free, it will be corrected soon. In that specific structure I thought (if suffix where 24 bits long) that I had 1 byte for prefix, 1 byte for page, inmediately next the 24 bits corresponding to the suffix and next to it the remaining 8 bits of the 4 bytes reserved for the uint32_t type defined last, Am I wrong or right?.

Comment: Hi @brhans, about the pageEvent struct there is a mistake, the suffix member should be a bitfield of 24 bits like it is defined in the other structures lefting the other 8 bits free, it will be corrected soon. In that specific structure I thought (if suffix where 24 bits long) that I had 1 byte for prefix, 1 byte for page, inmediately next the 24 bits corresponding to the suffix and next to it the remaining 8 bits of the 4 bytes reserved for the uint32_t type defined last, Am I wrong or right?. ->

Comment: I'm not understood if what you explained is that the compiler is arranging the structure on pieces that have the size of the biggest type or something else. I ask this because I did that code because I read part of the structure chapter of the Horton book Beggining C. From Novice to Professional and it the page 410 it has a figure where is explained how is arranged the memory in a structure. I'll put that figure as an update in the original post.

Comment: The example struct from the book that you've edited into your question doesn't have any alignment issues. The 1st 2 `int` fields are perfectly aligned on 4-byte boundaries (position 0 and position 4). The remaining `char` arrays will be at position 8, 28 & 48 - and these are not misaligned because even though they're 20-byte arrays, they're accessed as their individual bytes - and so don't need any special alignment modifications.

Comment: Changing `pagEvent.suffix` to a 24-bit-field doesn't change the underlying alignment requirement because it's still being stored as a 4-byte `uint32_t`, and therefore will be placed by the compiler on a 4-byte address multiple with spare 'invisible' bytes stuffed in. Unless you pack that struct, your `suffix` field will not immediately follow on from `head.page`.

Comment: Well I think I understood what you just told me, I'll do some modifications and I'll be in touch. Thanks again

Comment: Something you can do to check the before packing and after packing effects is to print out the size of each struct using `sizeof()`. I'd expect that before packing, `sizeof(pageEvent)` would be 8 (even with `suffix` as a 24-bit field), and after packing it would be 6 (or 5 with `suffix` as a 24-bit feld).

Comment: Thank you so much @brhans, after you told me about the I need to pack those structures I read some in the internet and finally the code works with all the commands, now I have to make several modifications to make it work with the rest of the code

Comment: Now how can I mark the question as solved?

Comment: By accepting my answer - which it seems you've already done.